# With ActionbarSherlock library, how can I make customized action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have successfully imported [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) library to my own project, and I can already see the sherlock made action bar in my application when I run my project.

But, now, everything is by default. How can I make a **custom action bar** with **sherlock** library ? Any tutorials available?

Comment: I made a template for custom ActionBarSherlock style. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757400/setting-actionbarsherlock-theme-for-android-app/#answer-14366287.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never used the `ActionBarSherlock` library (I have used [Greendroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) in the past, but now I use [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) for pre-honeycomb devices, which is great and very easy to use.).

That being said, I suggest you to look a the `res/values` folder where you will probably find all the default styles (probably wrapped in a custom theme which extends the default android theme). From there, you just have to extend that Sherlock theme and override the styles with your own.

If you want a good tutorial on how styles and themes work in Android, I suggest you to read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

**Edit**

In order to use `ActionBarCompat`you have to do the following:

1. Import the project from the samples directory (inside the directory where the android SDK is installed). (Note that you should download the latest SDK).
2. Remove `MainActivity` from the build path (right click on the class -> Build Path -> Exclude).
3. Set the project as a project library (right click on the project -> properties -> android -> check *Is Library*).
4. Add this project as a library for your app (right click on the project -> properties -> android -> click on Add in the Library section).
5. Make your activities inherits from `ActionBarActivity`.
6. Set the theme as `@style/appTheme` in the manifest.

Finally, don't forget that the action bar actions are in the `res/menu/main.xml` file. And same thing for the colors and styles, look at the `res/values`directory.

Comment: Hi, ActionBarCompat looks great, but how to use it, the link you provide only contain source code. any tutorials about it???

Comment: And where can I download the source code as a compressed file for the ActionBarCompat link you provided??

Comment: if I use ActionBarCompat as a library for my own project, does the final build APK file of my own project include the ActionBarCompat ?

Comment: @ Amokrane, I did your steps, and got error in my own project "No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.Holo.Light'", is it because my own project built target is Android 2.1 API 7??

Comment: @Leem.fin Yes, you have to set the build target to a version higher than 11 actually (honeycomb).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Amokrane's answer wasn't working for me, so here's how I solved it for anyone else that is having issues. I will simply copy and update Amokrane's answer

In order to use `ActionBarCompat`you have to do the following:

1. Import the project from the samples directory (inside the directory where the android SDK is installed). (Note that you should download the latest SDK).
2. Remove `MainActivity` from the build path (right click on the class -> Build Path -> Exclude).
3. Set the project as a project library (right click on the project -> properties -> android -> check *Is Library*).
4. <strike>Add this project as a library for your app (right click on the project -> properties -> android -> click on Add in the Library section).</strike> *Build the project and copy /bin/ActionBarCompat to you projects /libs directory.*
5. *Copy the contents of ActionBarCompat/res to your project /res directory, **being careful not to over-write any of your own resources**.*
6. Make your activities inherits from `ActionBarActivity`.
7. Set the theme as `@style/appTheme` in the manifest.

I hope this helps!