# java.lang.RuntimeException Theme.Sherlock

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, runtimeexception

I have put an update on google play and see this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.jim2/com.jim2.SettingWidgetActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1007)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:919)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
at com.jim2.SettingWidgetActivity.onCreate(SettingWidgetActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
... 11 more
```

I don't understand why this error appear cause it's work perfectly on my devices

Anyone have an idea ?

Here is a part of my Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`.

Use `setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);` inside `OnCreate`.

E.g.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // What you want to do here
}
```

Comment: Normally it's the same like i do isn't it ?

Comment: @jaumard Yes, you can do that too, but it isn't necessary. You do need to put the setTheme() in the OnCreate, or it will crash.

Comment: Thanks but error was fix i don't know how... maybe a compilation error with eclipse. I don't want to use setTheme on all my activities if i can put only once in my manifest.

Comment: It's a requirement from the `ActionBarSherlock`. Usually I make a BaseActivity for all code I want to copy onto all other activities, and then extend all the other activities from that BaseActivity. So you could write it once in whatever your base activity is.

Comment: From official ActionbarSherlock documentation: "The themes should be defined in your manifest for the entire application or on a per-activity basis. You may also define the theme in the code of each activity before calling super.onCreate(Bundle)".
http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

Comment: @JakeWharton Hey, thanks for commenting, Jake! Would you mind supplying/linking an example that shows the right way to do it? Because a lot of us are stuck on this, and this is the best hack that's worked consistently so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make your style inherit from Theme.Sherlock

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
```

then in manifest use your theme

```
android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
```

You do not have to use setTheme on every page as Muz said this seem like a lot of work when there are much better solutions, would mark the above answer down but I can't !!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with matt_lethargic. In my style file was:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

My application stoped crashing after I changed it to:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
```